# If $A$ and $B$ are nonempty, bounded subets of $\mathbb R$, then $ \boldsymbol{\sup (A\cap B) \leq \sup A}$.

Tags: real-analysis

If the statement is true, then provide a proof. If the statement is false, then provide a counterexample.

From my understanding, I think this statement is false because the $\sup A$ has to be greater than the intersection of $\sup A \cap B$.

Comment: That's what is written.

Comment: @Bernard it was not before some edits. Now question title and the OPs thoughts are contradictory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**

For $x\in A\cap B$,
$$
x\leq\sup A
$$
since $A\cap B\subset A.$

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** $A \cap B \subset A$. What does this tell you about the sup?